# How to convert a JavaScript array to a tree-like structure

Tags: javascript, arrays

Is there a way in JavaScript (preferably map, reduce, filter, etc.) to convert an array say:

```
sample = 
[
 "vegetable ! tomato", 
 "vegetable ! broccoli", 
 "fruit ! apple",
 "fruit ! orange",
 "fruit ! banana"
]
```

to the expected output (joined by `<br/>`) like so:

```
"vegetable samples are:<br/>
   tomato<br/>
   broccoli<br/>
 fruit samples are:<br/>
   apple<br/>
   orange<br/>
   banana<br/>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- No persisting variables/function creation
- pure map-reduce
- no repeated function creation
- works if your data is both out-of-order
- even if it's not deliniated by a perfect ' ! '

```js
Array.from([
    'vegetable ! tomato',
    '  fruit ! orange   ',
    'vegetable ! broccoli',
    'fruit!apple',
    'fruit ! banana'
]
    .reduce(
        ({map,match}, str) => {
            let [type, item] = str.match(match).slice(1, 3);
            ((map.has(type)) ? map : map.set(type, []))
                .get(type)
                .push(item)
            return {match, map}
        },
        {map:new Map(), match:/^\s*(\S(?:.*\S))\s*!\s*(\S(?:.*\S|))\s*$/}
    )
    .map
    .entries()
)
    .map(([type, items]) => (
        `${type} samples are:<br/>\n  ${items.join('<br/>\n  ')}<br/>`
    ))
    .join('\n')
```

output:

```js
"vegetable samples are:<br/>
  tomato<br/>
  broccoli<br/>
fruit samples are:<br/>
  orange<br/>
  apple<br/>
  banana<br/>"
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be:

```
var sample = 
[
 "vegetable ! tomato", 
 "vegetable ! broccoli", 
 "fruit ! apple",
 "fruit ! orange",
 "fruit ! banana"
]

var tmp = {}

for (var i = 0; i < sample.length; ++i) {
  var entry = sample[i]
  var type = entry.substr(0, entry.indexOf("!")).trim()
  var name = entry.substr(entry.indexOf("!")+1).trim()

  if (!(type in tmp)) {
    tmp[type] = []
  }

  tmp[type].push(name)
}

var result = "";

for (var type in tmp) {
  result += type + " samples are:<br/>"
  result += tmp[type].map(function(item) {
    return "  " + item
  }).map(function(item) {
    return item + "<br/>"
  })
}

console.log(result)
```

Comment: impressive, you sure made quick work of this one.  should actually be `.map(x=>x+'<br>')` and not `join` since his example has `<br>` after every node.

Comment: I think you need a linebreak too.  Although if it's HTML, unless it's in a pre, not sure what those whitespaces are for.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible implementation using a more functional approach (reduce, map). It could be tweaked to include the trailing `<br />` on the same line as the last entry in each category if that's something you care about.

I'd recommend using a list instead of `<br />` (first demo), but if you need to go the other route for whatever reason, see the second demo below.

### As lists:

```js
const sample = 
[
 "vegetable ! tomato", 
 "vegetable ! broccoli", 
 "fruit ! apple",
 "fruit ! orange",
 "fruit ! banana"
]

const separator = ' ! ' // could omit the spaces and trim() items instead

// utility to group by type, e.g. { vegetable: ['tomato', 'broccoli'], fruit: [...] }
const group = sample => sample.reduce((acc, entry) => {
  const [category, item] = entry.split(separator);
  acc[category] = [...(acc[category] || []), item];
  return acc;
}, {});

function asList (sample) {
  return Object.entries(group(sample)).map(([cat, items]) => (
    `<li>${cat} samples are: <ul>${items.map(item => `<li>${item}</li>`).join('')}</ul></li>`
  )).join('');
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = asList(sample);
```

```html
<ul id="output"></ul>
```

---

### The `<br>` version:

```js
const sample = 
[
 "vegetable ! tomato", 
 "vegetable ! broccoli", 
 "fruit ! apple",
 "fruit ! orange",
 "fruit ! banana"
]

const separator = ' ! ' // could omit the spaces and trim() items instead

// utility to group by type, e.g. { vegetable: ['tomato', 'broccoli'], fruit: [...] }
const group = sample => sample.reduce((acc, entry) => {
  const [category, item] = entry.split(separator);
  acc[category] = [...(acc[category] || []), item];
  return acc;
}, {});


function asString (sample) {
  // this could be tightened up if you don't care about preserving the whitespace and line breaks
  return Object.entries(group(sample))
    .map(([cat, items]) => (
`${cat} samples are:<br/>
  ${items.join(`<br/>
  `)}
`)).join(`<br/>`);
}

document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = asString(sample);
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```